# ConcurrentDictionary updates and enumeration thread sync

Tags: concurrency, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

I have 1.N threads writing to a .net 4.0 ConcurrentDictionary. I have another thread which fires every 5 seconds (settable in app.config) to enumerate the dictionary, and potentially remove some items. I want to halt the write operations during the enumeration.

What would be the best primitive to synchronize these two operations. Any help would be appreciated.

Bob.

Answer (score 2):

use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(VS.90).aspx) so enumerating thread will request exclusive lock and writing threads non-exclusive.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be stopping the updates to the collection. It seems to be ceeding control back from the enumeration thread meaning the enumeration thread isn't seening the full dictionary. The locks being released during the enumeration.

Comment: are you sure you followed my advice correctly? enumeration must require exclusive lock, this means that it can't be interrupted

Comment: Yip. but i've coded around it. I thought it would work, as I thought ReaderWriterLockSlim for sync would be the first choice before I posted the question.

Comment: Andrey, I'll dig it out and post it.